# How to take variables entered in the userform text box to the array text in the module using VBA in PowerPoint?

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint, userform

I have a macro to select slides, with required text, to move to a new presentation.

I have to extract 70-80 slides from a 500+ slides presentation. But I need to enter VB/Module to change the keywords/search text in the array. Is there a way I can move the text entered in the userform to the array (text)?

***Userform to enter the keywords.***

[image]

How do I link the text entered with the array list in the code?

```
Sub selct()

Dim pres1 As PowerPoint.Presentation, pres2 As PowerPoint.Presentation, 
pp  As Object
Set pp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

Set pres1 = pp.ActivePresentation
Set pres2 = pp.Presentations.Add

Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim TargetList

'~~>  Array of terms to search for
TargetList = Array("Agenda", "Review", "third", "etc")

'~~> Loop through each slide
For Each sld In pres1.Slides
    '~~> Loop through each shape
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        '~~> Check if it has text
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

            For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
                '~~> Find the text
                Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i))

                '~~~> If found
                Do While Not rngFound Is Nothing
                    '~~> Set the marker so that the next find starts from here
                    n = rngFound.Start + 1
                    '~~> Chnage attributes
                    With rngFound.Font
                        .Bold = msoFalse
                        sld.Copy
                        pres2.Slides.Paste
                        '~~> Find Next instance
                        Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i), n)
                    End With
                Loop
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form objects are accessible even when the form is not shown, like this: Suppose you have a form with name `UF1` with a textbox named `TBforKeyWord`, then you can access the textbox value at `UF1.TBforKeyWord`, so you might

```
 Redim Preserve TargetList(Ubound(TargetList) + 1)
 TargetList(Ubound(TargetList) = UF1.TBforKeyWord
```

The logic is the same if you let the user enter multiple keywords but then you need to work a bit more on splitting (and parsing) the keywords.

**EDIT**

```
 Dim text_array() As String 
 text_array = Split(SearchBox.Value, " ") 

 Dim iDimOld As Long
 Dim iDimNew As Long
 Dim i As Long

 iDimOld = Ubound(TargetList)
 iDimNew = iDimOld + Ubound(text_array) + 1
 Redim Preserve TargetList(iDimNew)


 ' Loop through each keyword in array 
 For i = 0 To Ubound(text_array)
      TargetList(iDimOld + i + 1) = text_array(i)
 Next
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply. Please note, I am just a beginner with VBA. I know the goal of this effort but yet to practice writing codes myself. Given the exigency at work, I am just trying to find codes available and edit the much I can with the limited knowledge I have currently. I see the below code helps me split the keywords. Can you help me add your code and this one to the first module (that is working with manual entry of keywords in VB mode)?

Comment: Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
 
    Dim text_array() As String
    Dim keyword As Variant
 
    ' Save all keywords into text_array
    ' Use Split to extract words from the search box, separated by spaces
    text_array = Split(SearchBox.Value, " ")
    
    ' Loop through each keyword in array
    For Each keyword In text_array
        ' Show that keyword is in array
        MsgBox (keyword)
 
        ' Do search with keyword here...
    Next
 
End Sub

Comment: Many thanks for your kind response. I will keep you posted on my progress.